# stop foreach inside a while loop when condition is met

Tags: powershell

I want to check whether there is a file in all drive letters, copy it to another drive, and stop searching on others if it is found.

```
While (Test-Path D:\folder\1.txt)
{
    Foreach ($dir in @("E:","F:","G:"))
    {
        IF (Test-Path $dir\folder\1.txt)
        {
            Copy-Item $dir\folder\1.txt D:\folder -Force
        }
    }
}
```

But script first finds 1.txt on E drive, copy it, then finds 1.txt on F drive and copy. How make it stop, when file is found on the first drive?

Comment: You can use `break` to exit the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `break` keyword. Also you don't need the while loop here:

```
    Foreach ($dir in @("E:","F:","G:"))
    {
        IF (Test-Path $dir\folder\1.txt)
        {
            Copy-Item $dir\folder\1.txt D:\folder -Force
            break
        }
    }
```

Comment: It works! (But I can not mark it as an answer yet) So it's not so rationally to use 'While'?

Comment: Your while doesn't makes sense in your example because you wan't to iterate over E, F, and the G drive and try to copy a file and stop doing so when the file was found in any drive. The while loop is obsolete.

Comment: Should I use break method two times after "Copy-Item",  if I copy two different files to the same folder?

Answer (score 1):

You need a condition to stop the loop. In this case it looks like you want to stop when the file D:\folder\1.txt exists. So the condition is true while the file does not exist. ex:

```
While (-not (Test-Path D:\folder\1.txt)) {
    Foreach ($dir in @("E:","F:","G:")) {
        IF (Test-Path $dir\folder\1.txt) {
            Copy-Item $dir\folder\1.txt D:\folder -Force
        }
    }
}
```